Missing field after a document Insert/Update in mongodb through C#
I have a migration script that tries to insert data into mongodb. I build the document object and insert it into a collection. The main document object has a bson element that has a recursive/nested element within itself.
I use a dbcontext to insert/update to mongodb. The only property that's missing is the recursive/nested property. I can see the rest of the data. Am I missing something here ?
public class Store 
{
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Id")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("isActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("rows")]
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]  
public class Row
{
    [BsonElement("rowId")]
    public int RowId { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("size")]
    public int Size { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("subRows")]
    public List<Row>? SubRows { get; set; }
}

I see the field Rows, but I do not see the field SubRows in the database. However I see the data exist in the document object just before context.SaveChanges() is executed.
